# make Toast if there is not data from server for word i entered in my edittext

Tags: java, android

I want to Toast if it wont recieve similar result to my word I enterd in edittext it should Toast me "No Result". But as it gets data after 0.5 seconds. So when I click button to check, first it Toasts "No results" then gets data and show them in recyclerview. I need if there is no similar word it toast me "No result" at the end.

**ActivitySearch.java**

```
String text = txtsearch.getText().toString();
new AsyncTaskSearch("http://192.168.1.100/afgApp/search.php", text).execute();

final Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
              if (!Activity_Search.data.equals("")) {
                  Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, data, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    timer.cancel();
                }else {
                  Toast.makeText(Activity_Search.this, "No results", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }
            }
        });
    }
},1,500);

Activity_Search.data = "";
```

**AscynktaskSearch.java**

```
public class AsyncTaskSearch extends AsyncTask{

    public String link="";
    public String text="";

    public AsyncTaskSearch(String link,String text){
        this.link=link;
        this.text=text;
    }

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        try{
            String data= URLEncoder.encode("text","UTF8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(text,"UTF8");

            URL url=new URL(link);
            URLConnection connection=url.openConnection();

            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            OutputStreamWriter writer=new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
            writer.write(data);
            writer.flush();
            BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();

            String line=null;

            while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                builder.append(line);
            }

            Activity_Search.data=builder.toString();
        }catch (Exception e){
        }

        return "";
    }

}
```

Comment: in your async task override on post execute and show toast here only because async task work in background thread after completed that task on Post execute() is triggered, so you should use here for any UI changes or something else

Answer (score 1):

you must put your toast messages in onPostExecute method

Answer (score 1):

You can make the following changes in your code:

```
public class AsyncTaskSearch extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>{
    public String link="";
    public String text="";
    boolean result = false;


    public AsyncTaskSearch(String link,String text){
        this.link=link;
        this.text=text;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Object[] params) {
        //write your logic to match your word
        if(word matches){
            result = true;
        }else{
            result = false
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {
        if(success){
            //word match found
            //show success toast
        }else{
            //word match not found
            //show failure toast
        }
    }
}
```